# Speech Emotion recognition, Google Colab, Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, speech-recognition

I am making my college project in Speech emotion recognition and I am trying to run these 3 blocks of code but I am getting a long list of error so kindly please help me

here is the link to google colab
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yHyLBbwVhsqiF8bUvd7_7YFDvOhaqzgz#scrollTo=UVbUUU2ueuYC

```
def extract_feature(file_name, mfcc, chroma, mel):
    with soundfile.SoundFile(file_name) as sound_file:
        X = sound_file.read(dtype="float32")
        sample_rate=sound_file.samplerate
        if chroma:
            stft=np.abs(librosa.stft(X))
        result=np.array([])
        if mfcc:
            mfccs=np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
            result=np.hstack((result, mfccs))
        if chroma:
            chroma=np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(S=stft, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
            result=np.hstack((result, chroma))
        if mel:
            mel=np.mean(librosa.feature.melspectrogram(X, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
            result=np.hstack((result, mel))
        return result
```

```
emotions={
    '01':'neutral',
    '02':'calm',
    '03':'happy',
    '04':'sad',
    '05':'angry',
    '06':'fearful',
    '07':'disgust',
    '08':'surprised'
}
observed_emotions=['calm', 'happy', 'fearful', 'disgust']
```

```
def load_data(test_size=0.2):
    x,y=[],[]
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/gdrive', force_remount=True)
    for file in glob.glob(f"/gdrive/MyDrive/datatset/Actor_*/*.wav"):
        file_name=os.path.basename(file)
        emotion=emotions[file_name.split("-")[2]]
        if emotion not in observed_emotions:
            continue
        feature=extract_feature(file, mfcc=True, chroma=True, mel=True)
        x.append(feature)
        y.append(emotion)
    return train_test_split(np.array(x), y, test_size=test_size, random_state=9)
```

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=load_data(test_size=0.25)
```

Below are the errors which I am receiving

```
Mounted at /gdrive
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParameterError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-03a67f23ae57> in <module>()
----> 1 x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=load_data(test_size=0.25)

3 frames
<ipython-input-77-e0a93a2717f9> in load_data(test_size)
      8                 if emotion not in observed_emotions:
      9                         continue
---> 10                 feature=extract_feature(file, mfcc=True, chroma=True, mel=True)
     11                 x.append(feature)
     12                 y.append(emotion)

<ipython-input-66-c2424d41c241> in extract_feature(file_name, mfcc, chroma, mel)
      4                 sample_rate=sound_file.samplerate
      5                 if chroma:
----> 6                         stft=np.abs(librosa.stft(X))
      7                 result=np.array([])
      8                 if mfcc:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/librosa/core/spectrum.py in stft(y, n_fft, hop_length, win_length, window, center, dtype, pad_mode)
    215 
    216     # Check audio is valid
--> 217     util.valid_audio(y)
    218 
    219     # Pad the time series so that frames are centered

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/librosa/util/utils.py in valid_audio(y, mono)
    293         raise ParameterError(
    294             "Invalid shape for monophonic audio: "
--> 295             "ndim={:d}, shape={}".format(y.ndim, y.shape)
    296         )
    297 

ParameterError: Invalid shape for monophonic audio: ndim=2, shape=(172972, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means the sound file you have is in stereo. You need to change it to mono. You should try this. Since you are working in Colab, you should first check that you can import AudioSegment:

```
!pip install pydub
from google.colab import drive
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment
```

Then this should work

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("The path to your file.wav")
sound = sound.set_channels(1)  ## This sets it to mono
sound.export("/output/path.wav", format="wav")
```

Comment: from pydub import AudioSegment doesn't work in Google Colab

Comment: Edited my answer and tested it in Colab.